# Can I override a fixture from a plugin in another plugin?

Tags: python, pytest

Lets assume I have:

- pytest-3rd-party-plugin that provides a fixture cool_fixture
- pytest-own-plugin that provides the fixture cool_fixture but with "better" functionality than cool_fixture

I want my own cool_fixture plugin to be the one that is selected. I know the following:

- If I would have put that fixture in conftest.py, there wouldn't have been any problem, that would have been selected by the pytest runner. But I don't want to do that, as I am reusing this fixture in many projects.
- I know that I can just call the fixture better_cool_fixture, and all will be fine :) But the fixture name is so pretty, so I kind of wanna keep it that way.

As I have understood pytest, there is no defined structure, what fixture that will be used. With exception of fixtures in module, conftest.py etc...

So anyway around this, so I don't need to change the name of this beautiful fixture?

Comment: My solution ended up to move the fixtures that I want to override to a module that I just import in the conftest file. Not that bad... but not an answer to the question :)